# Native prebuilt shared library in Android Studio with experimental Gradle plugin

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to add a native prebuilt shared library to my project in Android Studio. I am using the **gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5**. However, whenever I try to add the prebuilt shared library to my application model, I get the following error:

> Error:Cause:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.PolymorphicDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate

The library is added into the application model how it is described by the [Google Gradle Experimental Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental):

```
repositories {
    prebuilt(PrebuiltLibraries) {
        binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
            sharedLibraryFile = file("/path_to_libs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/shared_lib.so")
        }
    }
}

android.sources {
    main {
        jniLibs {
            dependencies {
                library "shared_lib"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The crucial line is *library "shared_lib"*. There is no error if I uncomment this line.

Since this is not working, I have also tried to use the guide from [ph0b.com](http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/). They are using a different syntax for adding native shared libraries (I just left out the headers since I do not have a single directory including all headers):

```
repositories {
    libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
        shared_lib {
            binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryFile = file("/path_to_libs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/shared_lib.so")
            }
        }
    }
}

android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            dependencies {
                library "shared_lib" linkage "shared" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, this does not work as well. Android Studio does not copy my shared_lib to the apk file. Hence, I always get the following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader [...] couldn't find "shared_lib.so"

Can anyone tell me how I can include native prebuild library into my project? I am using *buildToolsVersion = '22.0.1'* and *compileSdkVersion = 22* as build parameters.

Comment: could you maybe try with hard coded path to .so instead of `${targetPlatform.getName()}` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that already. Gradle can definitely resolve the path since I get an error if I change the path to a non-existent file. I would still be glad if there is a solution to my problem. However, I temporarily solved my problem by not using prebuilt libraries anymore. I added all my necessary header files with `cppFlags.add("-I${file("./../../../projects/test/include")}".toString())` and the cpp files with `srcDirs += "./../../../projects/test/src/"` to jni. But it would still be better to be able to use prebuilt libraries.

Comment: could you run with `--stacktrace` and grab more of the error?

Comment: Could you solve the issue? (besides the temporary solution) I'm having the same problem trying to link my .so

Comment: Have you taken a look at the NDK samples from Google?  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one worked for me (0.6.0-beta6).

```
repositories {
    prebuilt(PrebuiltLibraries) {
        YourLib {
            binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a/libYourLib.so")
            }
        }
    }
}

android.sources {
    main {
        jniLibs {
            dependencies {
                library "YourLib"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like they just forgot to mention the "YourLib {}" part around "binaries.withType".

Comment: Thanks！ this works for me on gradle-experimental:0.6.0

Comment: I will mark this as a solution to the general problem. The syntax of @Zhur is the correct one. However, I think the UnsatisfiedLinkError is a more complex error that mostly has nothing to do with the Gradle file.

Comment: @budderick It has: due to incorrect Gradle file the shared library is not getting into APK. So at the runtime the linker can't find that library and throws the exception.

Comment: Yes, in this case your solution is correct. I just wanted to say that the problem might still be deeper. One of my projects worked with your solution, another one didn't.

Comment: I don't think this works in the latest gradle experimental setup.

Comment: I think it should still work. But if you need the library already during the compilation of the native code, you have to set the jni and jniLibs source set.